# Phrase 'akimbo to'

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, american-english

What does the phrase 'akimbo to' mean? I am supposed to fill in the blank for the sentence:

> The professor strives to remain <sub>...................</sub> to her field.

I don't know if 'akimbo to' is the answer but would like to know its meaning.

Comment: Where did you get this sentence? Were there any other choices listed? And why do you think _akimbo to_ would be related to this sentence? You might want to read [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for some tips on improving future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no expression ***akimbo to*** in English (you'll rarely encounter [***akimbo***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/akimbo) in any other contexts apart from *"She stood, arms akimbo"* and similar). The most likely "missing word" in OP's sentence is:-

> *The professor strives to **keep abreast of** her field.*
>
> [**abreast**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abreast) *- up to date with the latest news, ideas, or information*

(Note: - *remain* would be an unusual choice, *keep* or *stay* are much more likely.)

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of options if we get to change the preposition-  *relevant in* ... actually *relevant* could work with *to* too.

Answer (score 1):

The above sentence is from Manhattan Prep  5lb 2nd Edition for GRE under sentence completion, question number 12.
Akimbo is to keep hands on the hips with elbows turned outside. So the phrase *akimbo to* might mean to have attitude which we usually show when we keep our hands on hips and elbows outside. The correct fit for the sentence is *abreast of*

Comment: Thanks for adding the context of the question, and for the explanation of *akimbo*. This question is already answered and accepted (https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31652/27840) for 5 years, but your answer is worth a vote.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what "akimbo to" means either. You can find the definition [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/akimbo). I would perhaps suggest "[akin to](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/akin)" as a better way to complete this sentence.